# Stop IE users typing into the file upload input

Tags: asp.net, html, file-upload

My testers have discovered that if you type free text into a file upload input then none of the buttons on the page work until that text is removed (so the page cannot be submitted).

I am able to replicate this with the following ASPX code (with no code behind):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuTest" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Note that I haven't bound any handlers to the page; despite this, the page is submitted when the submit button is clicked only if no text is entered into the upload text box)

Is there any way to prevent users from typing free text into a file upload control?  It seems that this is only possible in IE - Firefox and Chrome natively prevent text from being entered into upload input fields.

I've seen solutions elsewhere which suggest hiding input and replacing it with a label / button combo, but this seems like it might cause more problems and work inconsistently across browsers.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have a upload application with a file upload input control and I have found that typing free text into the control does NOT keep my other buttons from working. Tested with IE7.

Comment: @DaveB I've updated with a self contained example which definitely exhibits the behaviour that I'm describing in IE6.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this 'feature' of the control in IE. The page I tested with had 2 forms on it and the buttons in the 2nd form still worked, hence my original comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per @Jer's suggestion, I was able to prevent input into the file upload without breaking any of the other functionality by handling `keypress` events on the upload.  Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready() {
    $('input:file').keypress(function() {
      return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this would work as expected, but have you tried: `<input readonly="readonly">`

Comment: That disables input completely in IE - the "Browse" button no longer works (although it doesn't appear disabled, it just do nothing).  Interestingly, adding readonly="readonly" does nothing in Firefox or Chrome

Comment: Can you add a keypress event that negates any input from the keyboard? Again, I'm not sure if this would work with the file input element-- just throwing out ideas.

Comment: Handling the keypress does work, thanks @Jer.  I've included my solution as an answer here.

Comment: Ironically I had to take my own advice today to fix an issue at work :-P

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is perfectly fine for all the existing file controls.

But in most of the practical situations, we provide functionality to add more file controls on the fly so that users can select more than one file.

Key for the solution in this case was the [`.live` function](http://api.jquery.com/live).

The solution will be as follows:

```
$('input:file').live('keypress', function() { return false; });
```