# file input in IE 7 is allowing to type into it

Tags: internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, browser-testing

I am having problem with `<input type="file"/>` in IE 7,
it is allowing me to type into it. This problem is not present in FF 3.6 and IE 8.0

Is this known problem?

And every body handles it with writing java script event to eat-out the key presses as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463640/stop-ie-users-typing-into-the-file-upload-input)?

Comment: Is your question whether this is a known problem? You linked already to the correct answer to your post. IE handles file uploads differently than other browsers.

Comment: yea.. I thought browsers would handle it automatically. Now I know why people hate IE.
I was trying to know if this is present in all IE < 8 versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `unselectable=on` property at that time.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Got this link somewhere about [testing on multiple IE in Windows7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/02/04/testing-multiple-versions-of-ie-on-one-pc.aspx), hope to be useful for anybody having this kind of problems.